# Useref returning an error when switching view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have an component with an useEffect method inside. And inside this useEffect method, there I created a useRef to handle some scroll effects and animations. Particularly, the   `const ref = useRef(null);` . It works fine, however, upon switching views where this ref is not being used, it gives an error. Please see below code and picture:

```
   import React, { useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Anchor, Link } from '../components/AllSvgs';

const Container = styled.div`
  position: relative;
`;
const Slider = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  .chain {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
`;

const PreDisplay = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 2rem;
`;

const AnchorComponent = (props) => {
  const ref = useRef({
    style: {
      transform: null
    }
  })
  const hiddenRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      let scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
      let windowSize = window.innerHeight;
      let bodyHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;

      let diff = Math.max(bodyHeight - (scrollPosition + windowSize));
      //diff*100/scrollposition
      let diffP = (diff * 100) / (bodyHeight - windowSize);

      ref.current.style.transform = `translateY(${-diffP}%)`;

      window.pageYOffset > 5
        ? (hiddenRef.current.style.display = 'none')
        : (hiddenRef.current.style.display = 'block');
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
      ref.current.style.transform = null;
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container>
      <PreDisplay ref={hiddenRef} className='hidden'>
        <Anchor width={70} height={70} fill='currentColor' />
      </PreDisplay>
      <Slider ref={ref}>
        {[...Array(props.number)].map((x, id) => {
          return (
            <Link
              key={id}
              width={25}
              height={25}
              fill='currentColor'
              className='chain'
            />
          );
        })}
        <Anchor width={70} height={70} fill='currentColor' />
      </Slider>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default AnchorComponent;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56ZMY.png)

I believe I am supposed to unmount the ref, however, when I do this it does not work. Please see below:

```
 return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    ref.current = null;
}
```

Anyone know what it could be? Thanks

Comment: Where are `ref` and `hiddenRef` attached/used? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese hey sorry, I shouldve included more code to show it. I updated my post to show where it is attached to

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this error in a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/useref-returning-an-error-when-switching-view-fz8bvn). You tagged this with `react-native` though. Think you could create a *running* [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/) that reproduces this issue for us to inspect and debug live?

Answer (score -1):

`ref.current` contains `null` on initialization.
When `ref.current.style.transform = 'translateY(${-diffP}%)';` is called inside `useEffect`, you try to assign a value to a property inside an object, but there is no object, as it is `null`.

To fix it, you can try initialize `ref` like so:

```
  const ref = useRef({
    style: {
      transform: null
    }
  })
```

Comment: hmmm...that doesnt seem to fix the issue. Still seeing the same thing

Comment: Can you try this line inside `useEffect` instead ? `if(ref.current && ref.current.style) ref.current.style.transform = `translateY(${-diffP}%)`;`